# Is there a non-degenerate bilinear form on $R^N$ with a one dimensional kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $M: \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $n >= 3$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form. Are there $M$, s.t. $dim(ker(M)) = 1$? What can we say in general about the dimension of the kernel?

Comment: no, it cannot be possible, take a look at the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! However I don't immediately see why the theorem forbids dim(ker(M)) = 1? We would just have dim(Im(M)) = n - 1.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it: We have a rank problem in this case. We need rank(M) to be full for non-degeneracy.